# Most Reliable Way to Serialize Object in Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I was wondering what is the **most reliable** way to serialize an object in a data attribute (e.g. `<div data-options="[jsonlike object]>"`) using c#. I want to get this data using *$.data()* and if data are not written in a good way (for example spaces), jquery fails to get a proper object and returns a string.

I have complete access to JSON.Net library.

Comment: whats the measure of "reliable" here?

Comment: Survives native conversion to javascript object without failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install the JSON.NET Nuget package if you don't have it already.
2. Use it. For example, in Razor syntax:

   ```
   <div class="my-component" data-options="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new 
      {
         active = true,
         name = "Foo",
         // ...
      })">
   </div>
   ```
3. Consume it:

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
     $('.my-component').each(function() {
       var component = $(this);
       var options = component.data('options');
       component.somePlugin(options);
     });
   })
   ```

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` will ensure the object is rendered as valid JSON, regardless of the presence of any weird characters like backslashes. Razor's `@` syntax will ensure the resulting JSON is encoded properly for an HTML context, so symbols like `<` won't cause problems either.